# Django ListView Multiple Pagination in Same Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-pagination, django-3.1

I was trying to make multiple pagination in the same page with out using any library.

I followed this [Multiple Pagination Method](http://www.shanegibney.com/shanegibney/django-multiple-pagination-in-a-single-template/) and successfully implemented it. However, one issue in  this is say if I'm on page 3 on *model_one*, I click on next for *model_two*, then *model_one* resets to page 1, and *model_two* goes to page 2.

Is there any way to retain the page of a table, while navigating through pages of another table?

P.S.: If there is any library, please let me know as well. Found two versions of Django-Endless-Pagination, both seems to be abandoned around Django 1.8-2.0, and are more for Python2 than 3.

TIA

Comment: Just pass the current pages for `model_one` and `model_two` every time with GET params: `href="?page2={{ model_two.next_page_number }}&page1={{request.GET.page1}}"`

Comment: This worked well, thanks!